# Calculating possible permutations in a grid with the given length?

Tags: math

I have a 4x4 grid full of letters. How can I calculate all possible routes from any point to any point that consist of 2 to 10 points?

All points within a route must be connected to another point within the same route vertically, horizontally or diagonally. For example you can go from A to B, A to E and A to F but not A to C.

Each point can be used only once in a route.

Here's an example of 25 possible permutations:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+
| E | F | G | H |
+---+---+---+---+
| I | J | K | L |
+---+---+---+---+
| M | N | O | P |
+---+---+---+---+

- AB
- ABC
- ABCD
- ABCDH
- ABCDHG
- ABCDHGF
- ABCDHGFE
- ABCDHGFEI
- ABCDHGFEIJ
- AE
- AEI
- AEIM
- AEIMN
- AEIMNJ
- AEIMNJF
- AIEMNJFB
- AIEMNJFBC
- AIEMNJFBCG
- AFKP
- PONM
- FGKL
- NJFB
- MNJGD
```

Now I should clear the question. I'm not asking HOW to get all the permutations. I'm asking what is the total amount of the possible permutations (i.e. an integer) and how to calculate it.

Comment: I think that's some variation of "Travelling salesman problem"(TSP). Maybe this answer will help You: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725396/how-many-routes-possible-in-the-traveling-salesman-problem-with-n-cities-and

Comment: It is not the Traveling Salesman Problem. The first idea that occurs to me is [Depth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but you can take a lot of shortcuts by symmetry...

Comment: It's not immediately obvious. But it most likely has been studied. One thing might be to calculate the first few terms for 1X1, 2X2, 3X3, 4X4 grids and plug the numbers into The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences https://oeis.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the question can be answered with basic DFS in java starting at top left at (0,0)

EDIT: I added `if(count(visited)>10) return;` for the constraint

```java
static int count=0;

static int count(boolean[][] b){
    int r = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b[0].length;j++){
            if(b[i][j]) r++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

static boolean[][] copy(boolean[][] arr){
    boolean [][] r = new boolean[arr.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        r[i] = arr[i].clone();
    return r;
}

static void dfs(int i, int j,boolean[][] visited) {
    visited[i][j] = true;
    if(count(visited)>10) return;
    count++;
    for (int k=-1;k<2;k++) {
        for (int l=-1;l<2;l++) {
            int r = i+k;
            int c = j+l;
            if (r>-1 && r<visited.length && c>-1 && c<visited.length && !visited[r][c]){
                dfs(r,c,copy(visited));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    boolean[][] visited = {
            {false, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, false},
            {false, false, false, false}
    };
    // dfs(row,column,initialize all to false)
    dfs(0,0,visited);
    System.out.println(count-1);

}
```

The above script just goes through each permutation and increments `count` every time since this includes the starting point (for example `(0,0)`) i have at the bottom `count-1`

Output: `105837` (edited from my incorrect original `1012519`)

for 2x2 starting at same place i get `15`. Which you can see from running

```java
static int count=0;

static int count(boolean[][] b){
    int r = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b[0].length;j++){
            if(b[i][j]) r++;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

static boolean[][] copy(boolean[][] arr){
    boolean [][] r = new boolean[arr.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        r[i] = arr[i].clone();
    return r;
}

static void dfs(int i, int j,boolean[][] visited,String str) {
    visited[i][j] = true;
    if (count(visited)>10) return;
    count++;

    str+="("+i+","+j+")";
    System.out.println(str+": "+count);

    for (int k=-1;k<2;k++) {
        for (int l=-1;l<2;l++) {
            int r = i+k;
            int c = j+l;
            if (r>-1 && r<visited.length && c>-1 && c<visited.length && !visited[r][c]){
                dfs(r,c,copy(visited),str);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    boolean[][] visited = {
            {false, false},
            {false, false}
    };

    dfs(0,0,visited,"");
    // "count-1" to account for the starting position
    System.out.println(count-1);

}
```

Output:

```
(0,0): 1
(0,0)(0,1): 2
(0,0)(0,1)(1,0): 3
(0,0)(0,1)(1,0)(1,1): 4
(0,0)(0,1)(1,1): 5
(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,0): 6
(0,0)(1,0): 7
(0,0)(1,0)(0,1): 8
(0,0)(1,0)(0,1)(1,1): 9
(0,0)(1,0)(1,1): 10
(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)(0,1): 11
(0,0)(1,1): 12
(0,0)(1,1)(0,1): 13
(0,0)(1,1)(0,1)(1,0): 14
(0,0)(1,1)(1,0): 15
(0,0)(1,1)(1,0)(0,1): 16
15
```

the same script with 4x4 instead last 6 lines of output are:

```
(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(3,2)(3,1)(3,0)(2,1)(1,2)(0,3): 105834
(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(3,2)(3,1)(3,0)(2,1)(1,2)(1,3): 105835
(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(3,2)(3,1)(3,0)(2,1)(1,2)(2,3): 105836
(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(3,2)(3,1)(3,0)(2,1)(2,0): 105837
(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)(3,3)(3,2)(3,1)(3,0)(2,1)(2,0)(1,0): 105838
105837
```

Comment: I don't know Java, so I ask: does this code enforce the requirement that each counted path have 2 to 10 points?

Comment: Yes, at least that was the intent. Each time the function `dfs(...)` is called `count` is incremented and `dfs(...)` is called for each new vertex

Comment: Your answer seems to differ from http://stackoverflow.com/a/40748411/1278155 I wonder why?

Comment: Am I correct in stating that your answer of `105837` only counts paths starting from point A, namely `(0,0)`? If so, could you confirm or disconfirm my count of `1626144` for paths starting at any point?

Comment: @Rory Daulton Yes your correct and if you mean the summation yes i do get `1626144`

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for your problem are complex enough that I doubt there is a simple mathematical calculation--at least I cannot think of one. Here is recursive Python code to find your path count.

```
SIDE = 4        # Length of side of grid
MAXLEN = 10     # Maximum path length allowed
SIDE2 = SIDE + 2
DIRS = (        # offsets for directions
        -1 * SIDE2 - 1,  # up & left
        -1 * SIDE2 + 0,  # up
        -1 * SIDE2 + 1,  # up & right
         0 * SIDE2 - 1,  # left
         0 * SIDE2 + 1,  # right
         1 * SIDE2 - 1,  # down & left
         1 * SIDE2 + 0,  # down
         1 * SIDE2 + 1,  # down & right
)

def countpaths(loc, pathlen):
    """Return the number of paths starting at the point indicated by
    parameter loc of length at most parameter pathlen, not repeating
    points or using points marked False in global variable isfree[]."""
    global isfree
    pathcnt = 1  # count sub-path of just this one point
    if pathlen > 1:
        isfree[loc] = False
        for dir in DIRS:
            if isfree[loc + dir]:
                pathcnt += countpaths(loc + dir, pathlen - 1)
        isfree[loc] = True
    return pathcnt

# Init global boolean array variable to flag which points are still available
isfree = [1 <= r <= SIDE and 1 <= c <= SIDE
          for r in range(SIDE2) for c in range(SIDE2)]

# Use the symmetries of the square grid to find count of paths in grid
allpathcnt = 0
for r in range(1, (SIDE + 1) // 2 + 1):  # do a triangular slice of the grid
    for c in range(1, r + 1):
        # Find the number of similar (by symmetry) points in the grid
        if 2 * r - 1 == SIDE:
            if r == c:
                sym = 1  # center of entire grid
            else:
                sym = 4  # center of column
        else:
            if r == c:
                sym = 4  # diagonal
            else:
                sym = 8  # other
        # Add paths starting at this kind of point removing those of length 1
        allpathcnt += sym * (countpaths(r * SIDE2 + c, MAXLEN) - 1) 

print('Total path count is ' + str(allpathcnt))
```

This code takes into account the requirement that paths have lengths between 2 and 10 by limiting the path length to 10 and removing the paths of length 1. The requirement that points are not repeated is fulfilled by using array `isfree[]` to note which points are still free (`True`) and which are already used or should not be used (`False`).

Python is a somewhat slow language, so I increased speed by moving some calculations out of the inner recursions. I used a surrounding border of always-False points around your 4x4 grid, removing the need for explicit bounds checking. I used a one-dimensional list rather than two-dimensional and pre-coded the offsets from each cell to neighboring cells in constant `DIRS` (for "directions"). I used a final optimization by not using all 16 starting points. There are 4 corner points like A, 8 side points like B, and 4 center points like F, so I just found the numbers of paths from A, B, and F and calculated what the total would be for starting at all points.

This version of my code can handle any size square grid and maximum path length. I checked my code by varying `SIDE` and `MAXLEN` separately to 1, 2, and 3, and checking the results for each point by hand.

The final answer I get is

> 1626144

I was interested to note that the section of code taking the most space is the part that determines the symmetries of a point in the grid. I have found other, more concise ways to do this, but they are all much less readable.

Comment: Your answer seems to differ from http://stackoverflow.com/a/40735121/1278155 I wonder why?

Comment: @unska: I also wonder why. Since I do not know Java I cannot check the other code. When I get time I'll do more checking on my own code, but so far it passes all my tests.

Comment: @unska: Now that Bobas_Pett has corrected his code to account for the maximum path length, I see the difference. His answer only counts paths that start from point A in the grid, while mine adds the counts starting at all points. I agree with his answer that there are 105837 length-limited paths from A, but there are also 109330 starting from B and 82039 starting from F. I have generalized my code for any size square grid and done more testing, and I am confident that my answer is correct.